# SQLDelight - Emit on Parent Tables when Child Tables are Modified

Tags: android, kotlin, sqldelight

I haven't come across an obvious way to emit notifications on parent tables when child tables are updated with SQLDelight.

Here is an E/R Diagram roughly outlining the structure I have in play:

[image]

Which translates roughly to the following database schema:

```
R(ID)
S(ID, parentId)
T(S_ID, attribute)
```

And these `.sq` files:

```sql
-- com/package/R.sq
CREATE TABLE R (
    ID Text PRIMARY KEY
);
```

```sql
-- com/package/S.sq
CREATE TABLE S (
    ID Text PRIMARY KEY,
    parentId TEXT REFERENCES R(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

```sql
-- com/package/T.sq
CREATE TABLE T (
    S_ID TEXT REFERENCES S(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    attribute TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(S_ID, attribute)
);
```

And what I'd like to happen is that when attributes of T are updated, `SELECT *` queries on S (and thus R) are notified, and likewise when attributes of S are updated queries on R are notified.

Has anyone come across a way to do this with SQLDelight?

In SqlBrite, I could specify a set of trigger tables on a query such that when any of those trigger tables are modified the query is re-run and the result set is emitted downstream. So I could declare my trigger tables as `R`, `S`, and `T` on `SELECT * FROM R` and modifications to `R`, `S`, or `T` caused that to be re-queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug in SQLDelight. here is the github issue for it: https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/1325

Comment: I appreciate the response. For now, I mimic the intended effect by using joins. The only downside here is that I get new interfaces generated for each join query defined that I may or may not actually use, but that's not a big deal. Love SQLDelight a ton, by the way!